# custom sort list in magento grid

Tags: model-view-controller, sorting, magento, model, magento-1.5

I am having magento grid sort option like bellow

1. Best Value
2. Price
3. Name

I want to modify it like bellow

1. My whislist
2. Price: High to Low
3. Price:Low to High
4. Designer:A-z
5. Designer:Z-A

Designer,Price are attributes so can add it list but how to make it ascending and descending sorting.

## **How can i sort product by "My Wishlist" ?**

I tried this

```
$this->getOrderUrl('mywishlist', 'asc')
```

But not working.

```
     $tbl_wishlist_item = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('wishlist_item');
     $tbl_wishlist = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('wishlist');
     $tbl_catindex = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_category_product_index');
     $tbl_price_index = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_product_index_price');

 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
  $collection->getSelect()
             ->join(array('t2' => $tbl_wishlist_item),'e.entity_id = t2.product_id','*')
             ->join(array('t3' => $tbl_wishlist),'t2.wishlist_id = t3.wishlist_id','*')
             ->join(array('t4' => $tbl_catindex),'e.entity_id = t4.product_id','*')
             ->where('t4.category_id = 3 AND t3.customer_id='.$customer_id);
```

I tried this collection it sorts the correct number of product.But does n't show any products objects like name,image,price and etc. What is the problem.

Comment: @JürgenThelen:I figured out the file toolbar.php in following path .app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php.the list is drawn using $this->_availableOrder this.I don't know where add things,and i'm not sure changing core file is good idea

Comment: If you set "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" to Yes for your "Designer" attribute - it had to appear in toolbar drop-down list (default theme). There is no point in adding sort order (A-Z, high-low) to the drop down list, you have arrow right to drop-down to change order (default theme). And what does it mean "order by My whislist"? I'm not sure I got your idea.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that arrow.But my client needs in dropdown.My whishlist is sorts only in whishlist products from that category.

Comment: @JürgenThelen : I added more information regarding to wishlist sorting .

Comment: Is wishlist a sort? Seems like it's an either/or value so must be a filter instead, in that case is the sort box really the best place for it?

Comment: @clockworkgeek:Yes you are wright.But client needs to sort the wishlist items in current  category